# Can you use a static method in WCF that accesses HttpContext.Current.Items?

Tags: c#, wcf, static-members, interceptor

I have an interceptor that picks data from a message header on a WCF request. See below:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    _CurrentRequest = request;
    SetupSecurityPrincipal();
    ThreadExtension.PersonID = GetIntHeader(HeaderKeys.PersonID);
    return null;
}
```

`ThreadExtension` (ignore the name, means nothing) is a class with static properties that provide a get/set to `HttpContext.Current`. See below:

```
public class ThreadExtension
{
    public static int? PersonID
    {
        get { return (int?)HttpContext.Current.Items["PersonID"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["PersonID"] = value; }
    }
}
```

So the problem is on requests from our web end to our WCF web services, sometimes the information in `ThreadContext` changes if we have 2 requests that happen close enough together, resulting in one person's data in another person's session.

So my question is, what are we doing wrong? Is the use of static properties here not the right approach? Ideally, we just need something that is tied to the request in WCF so we can get to it in a few places without passing the data around all the time.

Any help or advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why that Property static if it session dependent?

Comment: We're trying to have access to those values for the lifetime of the call for that one person without having to pass the values in for every call. I may be thinking of this wrong, but my impression is the static properties are a pass through to the HttpContext. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is your WCF using sessions (for example with a netTCP binding) ? How do you relate the "PersonID" to throughout the call ? Any reason not to use `HttpContext.Current.Items["PersonID"]` directly ?

Comment: then I don't see how this could work with static properties... you need to make is non-static and at least pass around a reference to the right ThreadExtension...

Comment: can you help me understand what the difference is between hitting HttpContext directly and using a static property is?

Comment: the static property has one value for the whole lifetime of your assembly... so if it is changed it changes for ALL (perhaps concurrent) WCF calls... hitting HttpContext.Current directly gives you always the the current context which can be different in different calls/threads even when having concurrent calls

Comment: thank you, just one clarification though. Hitting HttpContext.Current.Items["PersonID"] directly seems like it would be the same as using the getter of a static property. Why is that different?

Comment: I am not very good at explaining but here goes a try: imagine that your `AfterReceiveRequest` in one HttpContext.Current, then comes another request (reentry) before the first one assigns PersonID, when you arrive at the point to assign PersonID (first request) the HttpContext.Current has changed because of the second request or vice versa (race condition)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suspect line is:

```
_CurrentRequest = request;
```

WCF message inspectors are normally singletons so instance variables are effectively static. Setting this and then reading headers from it elsewhere in the class will lead to the non deterministic behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thank you random stranger... I owe you one.